# naive dictionary datastructure using \csname ... \endcsname; problem with nesting

Tags: data-structures

With the following I tried to implement a naive dictionary data structure. All works fine, except when trying to nest two such dictionaries. In the last line in the following code the result is "key2", when "val2" is expected.

I'm obviously missing something in how "\returnvalue.get" is expanded. Any thoughts will be appreciated.

```
\def\newdict #1{

  \expandafter\edef\csname #1 \endcsname{#1} 


  \expandafter\def\csname #1.set \endcsname##1##2{
    \expandafter\def\csname #1.##1\endcsname{##2}
  }


  \expandafter\def\csname #1.get \endcsname##1{
    \csname #1.##1\endcsname
  }


}

\newdict{dict1}
\newdict{dict2}

\csname dict1.set \endcsname{key1}{val1}
\csname dict1.get \endcsname{key1}        %prints 'val1'

\csname dict2.set \endcsname{key2}{val2}
\csname dict2.get \endcsname{key2}        %prints 'val2'

\csname dict1.set \endcsname{key3}{dict2}
\csname dict1.get \endcsname{key3}        %prints 'dict2'

\def\proxyname{dict2}
\csname \proxyname.set \endcsname{key4}{val4}
\csname dict2.get \endcsname{key4}              %prints 'val4'
\csname \proxyname.get \endcsname{key2}         %prints 'val2'

\edef\returnvalue{\csname dict1.get \endcsname{key3}}
\returnvalue                              %prints 'dict2'

\csname \returnvalue.get \endcsname{key2} %prints 'key2'
```

Comment: Why don't you use `etoolbox`, that might make your code easier to deal with

Comment: In my experiment the last line prints `val2`. But I added `%` to protect end of lines.

Comment: Unless this is for a 'can I do it' project, look up `l3prop` via `texdoc interface3`. You can easily write a document interface with `xparse`. I would personally avoid using `etoolbox if possible, I understand much of its functionality is being superseded by the LaTeX3 project.

Comment: @SeanAllred. Yes, it is actually just a bit of deliberate practice, but I'll take a look at your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several unprotected end of lines, which count as spaces. Some of those I added are not really relevant, but it's good practice to add them.

```
\def\newdict #1{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname #1 \endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1.set \endcsname##1##2{% <-- Important
    \expandafter\def\csname #1.##1\endcsname{##2}%
  }%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1.get \endcsname##1{% <-- Important
    \csname #1.##1\endcsname
  }%
}

\newdict{dict1}
\newdict{dict2}

\csname dict1.set \endcsname{key1}{val1}
\csname dict1.get \endcsname{key1}        %prints 'val1'

\csname dict2.set \endcsname{key2}{val2}
\csname dict2.get \endcsname{key2}        %prints 'val2'

\csname dict1.set \endcsname{key3}{dict2}
\csname dict1.get \endcsname{key3}        %prints 'dict2'

\def\proxyname{dict2}
\csname \proxyname.set \endcsname{key4}{val4}
\csname dict2.get \endcsname{key4}              %prints 'val4'
\csname \proxyname.get \endcsname{key2}         %prints 'val2'

\edef\returnvalue{\csname dict1.get \endcsname{key3}}
\returnvalue                              %prints 'dict2'

\csname \returnvalue.get \endcsname{key2} %prints 'val2'

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg. I just realized its because of the white space/unprotected lines.